# Как отправлять события Socket.io для определенного юзера?

Tags: node.js, сокет, socket.io

недавно начал изучать ноду и добрался до сокетов.
Что хочу сделать: приложение, которое отпраляет индивидуальные события для пользователей. 
Идентифицировать их необходимо по токену из URL. Так вот, как отправлять каждому юзеру свои события?
Например: юзеру с url localhost?token=1 - отправить «Привет», а юзеру localhost?token=2 - “Привет, как дела?».
Знаю, что сокет присваивает каждому новому пользователю свой id, но токен мне нужен для сравнения юзера с бд.
Вооьще, это возможно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если принципиально хочешь через сокеты, то необходимо где-нибудь хранить соединения, а затем их доставать и отправлять сообщения. Что-то типо:

```
const pool = {};
// ...
pool[userToker] = socket;
// ...
pool[userToken].emit("message", {...});
```

Для учебных целей это решение - ОК.

Но в продакшене я бы сделал вот так: 
1) Хранил бы в базе/кэше обновления для каждого клиента
2) Клиент бы раз в какое-то время спрашивал бы: "Есть что-нибудь для меня новое?"
3) Если в есть, то возвращать
4) Клиент бы после получения снова спрашивал бы...

Для этого почитай что такое [Long polling](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/long-poll)